# Lite version of PHP?

Tags: php, terminal

I was just wondering if anyone knows if there is a smaller version of php. I don't need any full-blown apache support I just need to be able to execute "php" to run a script in the terminal.

I already have PHP installed on the server, but I do not have access to running "php" in the terminal. I'd just like to run my script that I wrote in PHP.

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you install PHP?

Comment: Linux. I didn't install PHP. I'm using a University server.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this won't work for you, but on every Linux system with PHP installed that I've used, I've been able to do the following to run a php script from the command line:

```
$ php SCRIPTNAME
```

Alternatively, to see if you can run a php script, you could also try:

```
$ which php
```

If you have command line access to php, this should tell you the path to the executable.

Comment: Yah that's what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately php has not been set up to just be able to type "php" in the command line and have it work. I need to go to the path, and when I run it from the path is gives me "permission denied"

Comment: @Matt:  Alas, I know of no "PHP lite" (although I'm no PHP guru). I can think of three other things you might try:  1) Download, build, & install into your own directory tree from source (from php.net).  2) Download and install from a package (e.g. rpm if you're using Red Hat or one of it's derivatives) into your own directory.  (try rpmfind.net)  3) Ask your sys admin to give you access to the php command line executable.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Many Linux distros have a package that contains the CLI version of PHP. On modern Fedora and derivatives (RHEL, CentOS, etc.) that package is `php-cli`. If that package is installed (use `rpm -q php-cli` to find out) and you still cannot use the `php` executable then you should consider asking the system administrators why they've disabled it.

Comment: It's the same name on debian/ubuntu based systems.